# Running built in web sharing on El Capitan machine with OS X Server 5 Installed

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx-server

I have installed OS X Server so I can use time machine to backup multiple computers to a central drive. I would like to configure El Capitan web sharing instead of OS X Server's Websites because I find it difficult to configure websites using OS X Server. I've tried doing this but it doesn't appear to work.

`sudo ln -fs /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf`

Can someone tell me how to enable the built in web sharing instead of the OS X Server's httpd server?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

Gary,

OSX comes with Apache2 as part of the core OS.  In mavericks and up Apple removed the "Web Sharing" in system prefs but one can still switch on the server with the `sudo apachectl start` terminal command.

As far as I know - OSX Server app does not add another httpd but uses the core Apache2 - they are one and the same thing.  OSXS is only a visual tool to "user friendly" the experience.  One can do all the manual things, like editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as per usual, with the added benefit of being able to control it somewhat.

(This [guide](http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) gets you somewhat started if you wish.)